# Apache2ctl + PHP 5 Access errors

Tags: php, apache, apache2

On an Ubuntu 14.04 x64 bit install, I have a working Apache2ctl install which I will be using for an [MPOS install](https://github.com/MPOS/php-mpos) on my server. MPOS has been (from what it seems) so far successfully installed, however upon trying to test the install at the server's URL, it returns an error 403 (forbidden). I am using the below directory/alias configuration for the apache2 install:

```
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /MPOS/ "var/www/MPOS"

    <Directory /var/www/*>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
```

The URL that is followed is 'http://servername/MPOS', and from here it returns a 403 error, however the default startup page at 'http://servername' is able to be viewed. Removing the Alias for 'MPOS' and then going to 'http://servername/MPOS' instead returns 404 errors - viewing the error logs shows zero errors - only startup and shutdown "servername unreliably determined" warnings. The Apache2ctl service is running under "www-data" which has been given access to '/var/www/" using the commands:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

I am at a loss to what is happening - I have looked at other similar issues on other forums, applied the fixes for those and they have not worked. So, I have come here to attempt to fix the error 403.

Additional info:
The index.php for MPOS is located under '/var/www/MPOS/public/index.php'
The default startup page is still set to the default initial install welcome page
The Apache2ctl service is running under the user "www-data" although some instances of it do seem to be running under "root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving the MPOS data directory into "/usr/share" and applying an alias to "/usr/share/MPOS/public", along with a directory structure same as "/var/www" the 403 and 404 errors were no longer present, and everything loaded smoothly - CSS, images, js and all